# Show measurability for $\lvert f\rvert$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> > Let $f\colon (\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\overline{\mathcal{B}})$ a measurable function. Show that then $\lvert f\rvert$ is measurable.

In order to show, that $\lvert f\rvert$ is measurable, I have to show $\lvert f\rvert^{-1}(\left\{\infty\right\})\in\mathcal{A}, \lvert f\rvert^{-1}(\left\{-\infty\right\})\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\lvert f\rvert^{-1}\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$.

It is
$$
\lvert f\rvert^{-1}(\left\{+\infty\right\})=\underbrace{\left\{f=\infty\right\}}_{\in\mathcal{A},\text{ because $f$ is measurable}}\cup\underbrace{\left\{f=-\infty\right\}}_{\in\mathcal{A},\text{ because $f$ is measurable}}\in\mathcal{A},~~~~~~~~~~ \lvert f\rvert^{-1}(\left\{-\infty\right\})=\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}
$$
and for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it is
$$
\left\{\lvert f\rvert\leq x\right\}=f^{-1}([-x,x])\in\mathcal{A}
$$
and so, because $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\left\{[a,b]: a\leq b\in\mathbb{R}\right\})$ and $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\left\{(-\infty,x]: x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$
$$
\lvert f\rvert^{-1}(\left\{(-\infty,x]: x\in\mathbb{R}\right\})\subset\mathcal{A},
$$
which means that $\lvert f\rvert$ is measurable.

Is my proof right?

Greetings

Miro